# Angular 2. Change class ONLY of focused element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

I have few buttons and `div` elements. `div`s are hidden. I want to reveal the specific `div`, when the specific button is clicked.

For example: You click first button - only first `div` appears (appears by changing his class).

Code: **app.component.html**

```
<button class="BUTTON" (click)="isHidden = !isHidden">
</button>
<div class="ELEMENTTOSHOW" [ngClass]="{ 'subMenuShow':isHidden }">first
</div>

<button class="BUTTON" (click)="isHidden = !isHidden">
</button>
<div class="ELEMENTTOSHOW" [ngClass]="{ 'subMenuShow':isHidden }">second
</div>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent {
  isHidden = false;
}
```

**This solution is wrong** because when I click e.g. first `BUTTON` then both divs `ELEMENTTOSHOW` appear. It shouldnt work like that, it should only work on a specific div.

Any help appreciated.

**Edit:** 
here is my code preview on plunker:

> https://plnkr.co/edit/BQKanrtuoADClGLVSdBC?p=preview

Its not my whole app, only the mentioned, VERY simplified part.

> **I have added AngularJS tag, because you can give me a solution related with angular1 and I will just rewrite it into angular2.**

Comment: Could you provide a Plunker with the current state of your application? In the code snippets presented above there aren't any actual buttons, only <span> elements with a "button" class.

Comment: @TudorCiotlos https://plnkr.co/edit/BQKanrtuoADClGLVSdBC?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

I'd restructure it like this:

**HTML**

```
<button class="BUTTON" (click)="isHiddenfirst = !isHiddenfirst">
</button>
<div *ngIf="isHiddenfirst" class="ELEMENTTOSHOW subMenuShow">
    first
</div>

<button class="BUTTON" (click)="isHiddensecond = !isHiddensecond">
</button>
<div *ngIf="isHiddensecond" class="ELEMENTTOSHOW subMenuShow">
    second
</div>
```

**TS**

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
  // Declare the tag name in index.html to where the component attaches
  selector: 'hello-world',

  // Location of the template for this component
  templateUrl: 'src/hello_world.html',
  styleUrls: ['src/hello_world.css']
})
export class HelloWorld {

isHiddenfirst = false;
ishiddensecond = false;
}
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/BOLCoRY0SmLe8GZT3PUG?p=preview

Comment: Thanks, but it's not really dynamic. Upvote my question because I need 15 rep points to upvote your answer :P

Comment: I still need 4 rep to upvote, when I get it I will upvote u. If nobody else answers I will check it as the best answer.

Comment: I created another solution so that it's more dynamic:
https://plnkr.co/edit/dDIwSH6BFwIR0ZI10vlO?p=preview

I think your issue is that they are both appearing when isHidden is true because they're both set to show when it's true and hide when it's false